# Presenting a modal view controller from within Settings.app

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, inappsettingskit

I decided to use InAppSettingsKit for my app. However, certain settings require the user to use the audio input for custom setting. I was wondering whether there is a way of presenting a modal view controller from within Settings.bundle - getting the parent view controller that presents Settings.app to sense that a button/setting was changed and launch another view controller on top of this one to pick the new setting from audio input and pass it on to the setting.bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InAppSettingsKit comes with an extension that allows you to do exactly this.

Check the [Custom ViewControllers](https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit#custom-viewcontrollers) section in the Readme. 
Of course this works only within the app, not in the settings app. There are several option to differentiate the settings plists between Settings.app and in-App. See "[Custom inApp plists](https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit#custom-inapp-plists)".

Comment: brilliant, that's what I was looking for. I completely missed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no default mechanism for communication between Settings.bundle and your open app. The only way they can pass data between each other would be through NSUserDefaults.

If you were so inclined, you could store values into NSUserDefaults to indicate the last View Controller you had open, but it would have to be a manual process. Even if that were achieved, there is no place in Settings.bundle to perform logic to consume that value.